# Deploy to remote server via command line

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, web-deployment, msdeploy

I have a Visual Studio 2013 project. I need to deploy it to remote Windows Server via command line, is this possible?

I tried the following command:

```
MSBuild.exe C:\BuildAgent\work\e1434fd989e26b76\WebService.csproj /T:Package /P:Configuration=Release
```

This packages the project for me. Now what should I do to deploy it to the server via command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **new custom publish profile** from **visual studio**. After creating it **validate the connection** from visual studio.Save this profile.Now in `Properties/PublishProfiles` there will be the `new publish profile.pubxml`.

**After that try this.**

`msbuild "PATH_TO_SOLUTION_FILE" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="PATH_TO_PUBLISH_PROFILE" /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:UserName=USER_NAME /p:Password=PASSWORD`

If you are executing the above from solution file path then just mention the solution name and publishing profile name. There is no need to give the entire path.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a publishing profile and deploy by calling an msbuild.exe with:

> /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Foo

This is described here:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment